# How to skip labels on the x-axis with ApexCharts

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I'm trying to format an Apex Chart like this:

[image]

The idea is that there are tick marks every 15 seconds but the label is only displayed every 30 seconds.

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/peterkronenberg/pen/oNaERKP

The problem is that if there are too many labels, it gets too crowded as the Codepen shows (for the purposes of the example, I just made the width smaller)

How can I thin down the number of labels displayed, maybe showing every 2nd or 3rd one?
`hideOverlappingLabels` doesn't seem to do anything

[image]

Comment: One way to do it is to set the xAxis type to `"datetime"` and let it do its arrangement; in that case, the `tickamout` is ignored. If you want to keep numeric, just adjust the values in your code. Your current `tickamount` is 38; you can also work with the validation condition in `formatter`, from `timestamp % 30000 ` to say `timestamp % 60000`, etc

Comment: Also, the option to hide overlapping labels is under `labels:{`, `hideOverlappingLabels: true`, (see [xAxis options](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/)) but its effect is disabled (superseded) by`tickAmount`; so another options is to disable (delete)`tickAmount` and activate `labels:{hideOverlappingLabels: true, ...}`

Comment: "datetime" doesn't work.  It's not flexible enough.  It displays random labels instead of showing, say ever 15 seconds or whatever.